# OrientDB using LET values in subQuery

Tags: sql, orientdb

How can you use a `LET` temporary variable inside the `Where` clause in an OrientDB SQL subQuery.

Here is the context in wich I'm trying to use it.

```
select *, $t.d from Currency 
   let $t = (select createdDate.asLong() as d from 13:1) 
where createdDate.asLong() >= $t.d and  @rid <> #13:1 
order by createdDate ASC
```

The validation in the where statement for the dates does not work. The subQuery actually works on its own. The Query works as well when replacing `$t.d` with the result from the subQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$t.d` is an array so you are comparing something like `createdDate.asLong() >= [1234599]`

You have to do this: `createdDate.asLong() >= $t[0].d`